# ReferenceError callback is not defied

Tags: jquery, get

I am using $.get for the additional field to be populate but getting the below error in firefox. It is working for chrome and ie.

**ReferenceError: callback is not defined**

```
var count = 0;
$('#addAddr').click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();     
    count ++;
    var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addmore"; 
     if(count <=2){
            $.get(url, {count : count },callback);  
            function callback(data){                
              $("#addAddrDiv").before(data);
            }
        }            
});
```

this is not moving to method of java class. Could you please help me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hoisting is not properly happening in Firefox([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p09y26xd/4/)) if the function is declared in a sub block.

```
var count = 0;
$('#addAddr').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    count++;
    var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addmore";
    if (count <= 2) {
        $.get(url, {
            count: count
        }, callback);
    }

    function callback(data) {
        $("#addAddrDiv").before(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: @AratKumarrana see the code snippet above... move the callback function definition out of the `if` block

Comment: I solved this issue.

` if (count <= 2) {
        $.get(url, {
            count: count
        }, callback);
    },
    function callback(data) {
        $("#addAddrDiv").before(data);
    });`

Comment: @AratKumarrana that is the code snippet posted above

Comment: no need to move the function the below is working for me 

`if (contactCount <= 2) {
   $.get(url, {
    count : count
   }, 
   function callback(data) {
    $("#addAddrDiv").before(data);
   });
  }`

Comment: @AratKumarrana that is inlined callback... that also will work